# After you deploy your token, do people who want to buy your token do a transfer with you as the owner of the total supply of the contract?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

I understand there are a list of required functions to deploy in an ERC-20 or BEP-20 token, but **do I need buy and sell functions in my code** or do I just need the `transfer` function? I am assuming that the buyers will buy from my wallet as the owner of the total supply. However, people would be buying from an exchange, so does the exchange have liquidity pool providers buy a bunch of tokens from me at first in an IEO? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This completely depends on how you want to distribute your token.

Often this is separated between different components. E.g. you deploy your token and `mint` the initial supply to and `distributor` address. This `distributor` could be a contract that is used for an ICO, by selling the token for a specific price. Another way would be to use a MultiSig wallet, such as the Safe and sell the token via a platform like [Gnosis Auction](https://gnosis-auction.eth.link/#/). Additionally you can distribute tokens by performing airdrops (e.g. a [MerkleDrop](https://github.com/trustlines-protocol/merkle-drop/blob/master/contracts/contracts/MerkleDrop.sol)).

Often many of these are combined to archive the best result. An example for this can be seen in an early [proposal for a SAFE token](https://forum.gnosis.io/t/gip-2-safe-token-model/691) on the Gnosis Forum.